# Check if object in array contain all value in another object in array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I've spent a couple hours to compare of two object in array, but i'm not find a way to achieve it

Let say i've these array called `compareWith`:

`[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]`

and this is an array to be compared and the expected result:

1. `[{b:2}]` true -> because {b:2} is in `compareWith`
2. `[{c:3},{a:1}]` true -> because {c:3} and {a:1} is in `compareWith`
3. `[{a:1},{b:2}]` true -> because {a:1} and {b:2} is in `compareWith`
4. `[{a:1},{d:3}]` false -> because {d:3} is not in `compareWith` even {a:1} is in `compareWith`

how can i achieve the above result using javascript function/ lodash?

EDIT:

just tried this but i want a `boolean` as a result:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

var a = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]
var b = [{c:3},{a:1}]

let result = _.differenceWith(a, b, _.isEqual)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) //[{b:2}]
```

Comment: could you send us what you have even if it doesn't work

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I've tried many way using includes, some, find, difference of lodash function, and because i don't get the result, i just deleted what i've tried so far @AlwaysHelping

Comment: We need to see your attempts to achieve this ? Remember stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping sure, i know SO is not a coding service, that's why i use a simple case of an array rather than show my entire problem in my post

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
function compareWith(originalArray, arrayToCompareWith){

   for(let obj of originalArray)
      if(!arrayToCompareWith.find((x)=>_.isEqual(x, obj)))
         return false;
   return true;

}
```

or just in one line using lodash as follows

```js
var main = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}],
a1=[{b:2}],
a2=[{c:3},{a:1}],
a3=[{a:1},{b:2}], 
a4=[{a:1},{d:3}];

function compareWith(originalArray, arrayToCompareWith){

   return _.differenceWith(arrayToCompareWith, originalArray, _.isEqual).length == 0;
}

console.log(compareWith(main, a1));
console.log(compareWith(main, a2));
console.log(compareWith(main, a3));
console.log(compareWith(main, a4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i thought my question can be achieved with one liner code, something like `let isSame = _.difference(arrayToCompare, compareWith).length === 0`

Comment: have you tried _.differenceWith(compareWith, arrayToCompare, _.isEqual).length == 0;

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` vanilla javascript

```js
main = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]
a1=[{b:2}]
a3=[{c:3},{a:1}]
a4=[{a:1},{b:2}] 
a5=[{a:1},{d:3}] 

function check(main,a){
  res =main.filter(o=>a.some(e=>Object.keys(e)[0]==Object.keys(o)[0] && Object.values(e)[0]==Object.values(o)[0]))
  return res.length==a.length ? true : false
}
  console.log(check(main,a1))
  console.log(check(main,a3))
  console.log(check(main,a4))
 console.log(check(main,a5))
```